# I have a very big KML file, I want to remove all the placemarks from it

Tags: kml, xml, kmz

I want to remove all the Placemarks that has a name, and keep the lines which is between , as the performance of the file is awful

I've tried to do it using Notepad++ Replace function using the below

```
<Placemark>       <name>.*</name>

to be replaced by

<Placemark>       <name></name>
```

and its not working :(

Comment: An XML editor class in your language of choice would be a better tool for the task.

Comment: I am just trying to remove all the placemarks and keep the path(s) there in the KML file

Comment: I'm with @Vince on this. You might also want to look into using a dedicated XML Editor (e.g. OxygenXML or similar). Using regular expressions with XML can be a bit tricky (so as ahmadhanb says, take a backup first if you use Notepad++!). See also answers to [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/464905)

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 3.0 you can remove all the Placemark elements having a child called `name` using:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    <xsl:template match="Placemark[name]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

This sort of job is much better done using XML-aware tools rather than ordinary text editors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following regular expression in `Notepad++`, but before that take a backup of your KML file:

Find:

```
<name>[A-Za-z1-9]+<\/name>
```

Replace:

```
<name></name>
```

Also your expression will work after your escape the slash `/` in `</name>`

Find:

```
<name>.+<\/name>
```

Replace:

```
<name></name>
```

Use `Replace All` in `Notepad++`, and if it didn't work, use `Replace All in All Opened Documents`, assuming that the only file opened  is the KML file.

I tested the above expressions and it worked for me.